# Problem in tcolorbox sidebyside align

Tags: tcolorbox

My aim is to make some sort of solutions to exercises. I have got some idea on using `tcolorbox` stuff, but this alignment issue seems pretty weird.

Here is what I have right now.
[image]

What I want is, since 1.13 is some sort of problem index, It should go on top. I tried using `sidebyside align=top` but it doesn't work. How can I fix this issue?

The following is LaTeX code to reproduce above image.

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\parindent=0pt

\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,lefthand width=1.5cm]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,before skip=0pt,boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]
            {\sffamily \bfseries {\color{purple}\S 1.13}}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \tcblower
        \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,before skip=0pt,boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas to fix the issues?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `sidebyside align=top`works, but the suboxes are like two single characters aligned in the first (and   unique)  line at the baseline. Is the same problem that align `a` with `A`.  If you change    `\lipsum[1]\end{tcolorbox}`  by `\lipsum[1][1] \end{tcolorbox} \lipsum[2-3]` you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`side by side` alignment options include `top seam` which do what you want as it's shown in following first example.

Your example shows nested tcolorboxes. This means that the boxes are not breakable. If this is your intention, I've nothing to say. But, in any case, I propose a similar format, without the external box, which allows breakable boxes and an automatic counter for the boxes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\parindent=0pt

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{problem}[1][]{enhanced, attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight, xshift=-2cm}, left skip=2cm,
    colbacktitle=tcbcolback, coltitle=purple, fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
    boxed title size=title,
    boxed title style={text width=1.8cm},
    title={\S \thetcbcounter},#1
}


\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,sidebyside align=top seam,lefthand width=1.5cm]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,before skip=0pt,boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]
            {\sffamily \bfseries {\color{purple}\S 1.13}}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \tcblower
        \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,before skip=0pt,boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    \begin{problem}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{problem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and additional advice. I am completely new to this package (tcolorbox) and wasn't aware of such features. Your solution seems to work great!